# Is there a noun in latin for "failure"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, noun

I'm translating a song and its title is "failure"(the opposite of success) I could find some verbs with a similar meaning but I couldn't find a noun for "failure"

Comment: http://latin-dictionary.net/search/english/failure i add falsum, culpa, peccatum.

Answer (score 1):

Traupman gives *defectio*, *offensio*, and *ruina fortunarum* for "failure". These can all work, depending on context and usage. I like  *ruina fortunarum* best, myself, but it will all depend on how exactly you use it, and what exactly you mean. You might (depending on context) replace *fortunarum* with *operae* or *nisus* depending on whether you mean failure of outcome, or of construction, or of effort.